# What is error with cancan in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, authorization, cancan

I am using cancan to authorize the user in controller,And in views i am using `Can?`to check if the user is authorize to see that function

**index.html.erb**

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<h1>Listing Noticeboards</h1>

<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>society</th>
      <th>Notice heading</th>
      <th>Notice text</th>
      <th>Active</th>
      <th>Isdelete</th>
      <th>Expire</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>

    <% @noticeboards = @noticeboards.where(Isdelete: 0).find_each %>
      <% @noticeboards.each do |noticeboard| %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= Society.find_by(id: noticeboard.id_society, Isdelete: 0).name %></td>
          <td><%= noticeboard.notice_heading %></td>
          <td><%= noticeboard.notice_text %></td>
          <td><%= noticeboard.active %></td>
          <td><%= noticeboard.IsDelete %></td>
           <td><%= noticeboard.Expire %></td>
          <td><%= link_to 'Show', noticeboard %></td>
           <% if can? :update, noticeboard %>
          <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_noticeboard_path(noticeboard) %> <% end %></td>
          <% if can? :delete , noticeboard %>
          <td>
            <%= link_to 'Destroy', noticeboard, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td> <% end %>
        </tr>
      <% end %>

  </tbody>
</table>

<br>
 <% if can? :create, @noticeboard %>
<%= link_to 'New Noticeboard', new_noticeboard_path %>
<% end %>
```

In this if i change :delete to anything else, say :Hello, its still checking can, and if i am not using anything, it gives error saying "wrong number of arguments" what is the error, why its not taking :delete function?

Comment: can? :update uses the wrong noticeboard variable, it is @noticeboard, should be noticeboard though.

Comment: oh yes,i changed the code, its still not showing any errors and still following Can? @jfornoff

Comment: I'm not sure what the exact problem is for you, but maybe it helps you to know that CanCan just checks the permissions, which are not limited to the Rails default actions, so you could query can? :anything, noticeboard and get a true / false response (if you haven't defined it, it defaults to false). So it is correct that it's not throwing any errors.

Comment: maybe i couldn't explain my problem , It was authenticating even when am changing the method name, yes it will return false if method is not defined, but its Authorizing user and admin, Admin can still see destroy and users still can, if cancan cant find that method it should show destroy to users too, but its showing just to admin @jfornoff

Comment: Maybe you can update your post with your authorization settings for the different roles